# jQuery parents selector

Tags: jquery

I want to select a parent H2 depends on element which was clicked
Example :

```
<ul><h2>Title1</h2>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>sub menu
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<br/>


<ul><h2>Title2</h2>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>ubmenu
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
            <li>sub sub menu
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have 3 links that are in different places.
My JS function :

```
jQuery("a").bind('click', function () {    
       jQuery(this).parents("h2").html("okay!")

})
```

So, I want to change the content of the parent H2, link1 click change the title1 and both link2 must change the title2.

My test : http://jsfiddle.net/Kaherdin/awX9n/1/

Comment: The reason you're having trouble (alluded to in the answers below) is that you go up through the parental tree and H2 isn't there as it's a sibling of a parent rather than a direct parent.

Comment: @JeffWatkins: An Auntie of an Uncle one might say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`h2` is not a parent of the `a` tag so you must traverse up to the `ul` then find the `h2`

```
jQuery("a").on('click', function () {   
    jQuery(this).parents("ul").find("h2").html("okay!")
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/awX9n/4/

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
jQuery("a").bind('click', function () {    
   jQuery(this).closest("ul:has(h2)").find("h2").html("okay!")
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hpCCp/)

Note, you could make that selector much simpler and faster if you put a `class` or `id` on the top-level `ul`.

**Update**

Here's how make it simpler with a class on the parent `ul`:

```
<ul class="list-parent">
    <h2>Title1</h2>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>sub menu
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
jQuery("a").bind('click', function () {    
   jQuery(this).closest(".list-parent").find("h2").html("okay!")
})
```

Comment: Thanks, work great, but just for know, How it will simple with a class name ?

Answer (score 2):

OK so `a` doesn't have a prent of `h2`. But you can do this:

```
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('ul:has(h2)').find('h2').html('okay!');
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aZcCQ/)

This will first find the `ul` parent (which is the closest parent element that contains the `h2` you want) and then it will find the `h2` element.

It is important to note, that if your structure changes to include more `h2` element inside the parent `ul` then it will not work. But I am sure you are aware of those kind of things

Comment: The `ul` containing the `h2` is several levels above the clicked `a` - `closest()` alone won't find the right one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thanks missed that bit of the html

Answer (score 1):

`h2` element is not parent of the clicked element, you can add a class to the topmost `ul` elements and use `closest` method:

```
<ul class='parent'><h2>Title1</h2>
```

```
jQuery(this).closest("ul.parent").children("h2").html("okay!");
```

You can use jQuery selectors for selecting the element with your current markup, but using classes makes your code more cleaner and efficient.

Comment: +1, although it doesn't work with OP html, I much prefer to use classes in this way to find things more reliably

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("h2").html("okay!");
```

would do it.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this, all the h2 are changes and not only the parents one

Comment: Not true: this updates ALL `h2` elements, not the one contained in the same `ul` as the clicked `a`: http://jsfiddle.net/hpCCp/1/

Comment: upated the code, will work for a fixed markup, but if markup is fuzy, then you have to implement a more responsive solution.

Comment: This wont work for the second "link2". It is nested much deeper

Comment: Yeah, I try this put it works only in this example, if my Menu is generate it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try your code by using `find()` option, like

```
jQuery("a").bind('click', function () {    
     jQuery(this).parents("ul").find("h2").html("okay!")
})
```